# Create and overloaded function for Numeric and Integer Vector

Tags: r, overloading, rcpp

I know that we can't overload a C++ function in R according to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023726/create-two-r-functions-with-same-name-but-different-type-of-argument). But sometime we need it. The solution proposed to make a dispatcher in the  question linked seems a bit overkilled to me (using templates and switches). I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution for simple problems.

So here a simple problem. `x` is a vector of `int` or a vector of `double`. `sum(x == y)` can be written in a faster and memory optimized way in C++.

```
int int_count_equal(IntegerVector x, int y)
{
 return std::count(x.begin(), x.end(), y);
}
```

and

```
int num_count_equal(NumericVector x, double y)
{
 return std::count(x.begin(), x.end(), y);
}
```

The two functions have the same body. It does not make sense and it is not convenient to have two functions. How can we make a dispatcher in a single function `count_equal` without writing twice the same code?

Comment: You missed the fact that the C interface in the middle does not allow this.  Hence the existing solutions.  Wishing that the world was different is typically not enough to get it to change .

Comment: You're right I definitively do not understand why it does not work. I understand low level languages however understanding how R, C and C++ are interfaced to work all together is definitively beyond my knowledge. I'm naively expecting to get C++ behaviors writing C++ code. So the answer is *use `SEXP`, `switch`, `as<>()` and duplicated code*. Right ?

Comment: I use dispatchers. When I need to write the "same" dispatchers many times, I use macros.

Comment: Macros are bad. You can get the same with templates.

Comment: This has come up a few times. Currently the code generation that takes place between the C++ function(s) and the R function does not. It could with a little bit of non obvious work. In the meantime, you can either dispatch at the R level using S3 or S4 (in that case you would not use overriding in C++) or have the R function calling a C++ function that does the dispatch.