# Rcpp template class for custom input and output

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to create C++ function which will apply any funtion on R vector of any type. I've been reading and searching for an answer but my knowledge is still too chaotic and I can't put everything together. I was inspired by [sapply example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) and some from [Rcpp gallery](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/) but it's to advanced so far.
What I've already done is simple class which kinda-works, but I'm having problem even with this one. Error happens when I'm trying to call function which returns something else than numeric. However I don't know how to extend function to work with custom output type.

At this point, I don't know how:

1. Obtain type of R Function return value and use this type do define `out` - same size as `x`
2. Alternatively - use `std::string type` argument in `apply_fun` which could switch `OUTTYPE`
3. Pass any `x` to the class and use in `f` - I think I've managed this correctly with `<int XTYPE>`

Perhaps answer to this question might be to complex so I appreciate all hints. Below I present current progress. Thanks!

**Rcpp class**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace apply {

template <int XTYPE>
class SomeClass {
private:
  Rcpp::Vector<XTYPE> x;
  Rcpp::Function f;

public:
  Rcpp::Vector<XTYPE> run() {
    typedef typename Rcpp::traits::storage_type<XTYPE>::type STORAGE;
    int n = x.size();
    Rcpp::Vector<XTYPE> out(n);
    for (unsigned int i{0}; i < n; i++) {
      out(i) = Rcpp::as<STORAGE>(f(x(i)));
      // Rcpp::Rcout << out(i) << std::endl;
    }

    return out;
  }

  SomeClass (Rcpp::Vector<XTYPE> x, Rcpp::Function f)
    : x{x}, f{f} {
      std::cout << "Initialized SomeClass" << std::endl;
    }
};
}
```

**Exported Rcpp function**

```
//' @export
//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::RObject apply_fun(Rcpp::RObject x,
                        Rcpp::Function f) {

  if (TYPEOF(x) == INTSXP) {
    apply::SomeClass<13> r{Rcpp::as<Rcpp::IntegerVector>(x), f};
    return r.run();
  } else if (TYPEOF(x) == REALSXP) {
    apply::SomeClass<14> r{Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(x), f};
    return r.run();
  } else if (TYPEOF(x) == STRSXP) {
    apply::SomeClass<16> r{Rcpp::as<Rcpp::CharacterVector>(x), f};
    return r.run();
  } else if (TYPEOF(x) == LGLSXP) {
    apply::SomeClass<10> r{Rcpp::as<Rcpp::LogicalVector>(x), f};
    return r.run();
  } else if (TYPEOF(x) == CPLXSXP) {
    apply::SomeClass<15> r{Rcpp::as<Rcpp::ComplexVector>(x), f};
    return r.run();
  } else {
    Rcpp::stop("Invalid data type - only integer, numeric, character, factor, date, logical, complex vectors are possible.");
  }

  return R_NilValue;
}
```

**R calls**

```
apply_fun(c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5), f = function(x) { x + 10})
#  11.5  12.5   13.5

apply_fun(letters[1:3], f = function(x) paste(x, "-"))
#  Error in apply_run(letters[1:3], f = function(x) x) : 
#  Evaluation error: unimplemented type 'char' in 'eval'
```

Comment: Would overloading help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023726/create-two-r-functions-with-same-name-but-different-type-of-argument

Comment: Thanks for this link. It forced me to learn about operator overloading